# Show Images Upload in Admin using FileField in Django

Tags: html, django

I need to show multiple images uploaded in the Admin page (using FileField) in my html.

I'm currently using:

Python 3.6.0b4

Django 1.10.3

I can currently show if the model only has one image but when I try to put multiple images, I have no idea how to show it.

Here is my code:

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    name= models.ForeignKey(Product)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='media/',null=True,blank=True)
```

**admin.py**

```
class ProductImageInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ProductImage

class ProductModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('created_by',)

    inlines = [ProductImageInline]

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not change:
            obj.created_by = request.user
        obj.save()


admin.site.register(Product,ProductModelAdmin)
```

If I add

```
image = models.FileField(upload_to='media/',null=True,blank=True)
```

in my **model.py**, I can show it in the html like this:

```
<img width=200 src="{{product.image.url}}" /></a>
```

How can I show the Multiple Images in the html?
I'm fairly new to Django but have experience on web development.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have [many-to-one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) relation you can get all related to the object records using `<modelname>_set` property.

So try iterate through all images in productimage_set:

```
{% for image in product.productimage_set.all %}
    <img src="{{image.image.url}}">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot. Totally works. Can I ask one last question? How can I show the images uploaded in the Admin Page in the Editing the Model page. It only shows the file path leading to the Image. Thanks.